# Char* Function returning null from a value that is not null

Tags: c, string, pointers

So the problem lays in my circumcised String function. It is supposed to take a string, a char and an int array, give me back the string without the char, and mark all the chars that it removed.

```
char* circumcisedString(char* og, char rem, int* checked)
{
    char circS[100];
    char* t= circS;
    char* og2 = og;
    while(*og2)
    {
        if(*og2 != rem)
        {
            *t = *og2;
            t++;
        }
        else
        {
            checked[og2 - og] = 1;
        }
        og2++;
    }
    *t = '\0';
    printf("%d ", circS);
    return circS;
}

void Three()
{
    char str[100]; scanf("%99s", str);
    char rem[100]; scanf("%99s", rem);
    int strl = strlen(str);
    int reml = strlen(rem);
    int checked[reml];
    for(int i = 0; i < reml; i++) checked[i] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < reml; i++)
    {

        if(!checked[i])
        {
            char* remstr = circumcisedString(rem, rem[i], checked);
            printf("%d ", remstr);
            int j = 0, c = 0;
            //j = mystrstr(str, remstr) - str;
            //while(j = strstr(str + j, remstr) + 1) c++;
        }
    }
}
```

After printing "%s" of circS (which is my pointer to new string) I get exactly what I wanted, until I return it. When returned it only gives back a null adress. In the printf tests which are still in the code, "print("%d", circS)" puts out 6421472 as it's memory location, and printf("%d ", remstr) puts out 0. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local variable that went out of scope as soon as the function ended. [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: instead of looping through the entire `checked` array and setting everything to 0, you can simply write `int checked[reml] = {0};`. does the same thing but a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the array that `circS` is pointing to goes out of scope after the function ends, so the function's stack frame gets cleared and the address of the nonexistent array is no longer there.
When you call

```c
printf("%d ", circS);
```

the array is still in scope and the stack frame is still there, so the address that `circS` points to is still valid. Lets assume `circS = 0x0061FBE0`. When `circS` is returned, `0x0061FBE0` and puts it into `remstr`. However, because the array that `circS` pointed to went out of scope and stack frame was freed, `0x0061FBE0` no longer points to the array but to something else we shouldn't mess with, which makes it now a null address.

---

###### How can it be fixed?

You can directly modify the original string parameter and return the parameter (or return nothing at all and make it a `void` function) after you remove duplicates of a certain character.
If you need to save the original string, just make a copy using `memcpy`.

```c
char* circumcisedString(char* og, char rem, int* checked)
{
    // do something with og
    
    return og;
    // or return nothing
}
```

This code works because the parameters passed into the function are from the location of *where the function was called*, and after the function is finished, the parameters will still exist *where the function was called*, so when the function returns to where it was called, the memory will stay valid. (in your specific case, `og` will be a valid memory address, which is `rem`).